# How to deploy Laravel as backend and Nextjs as front end in VPS

Tags: laravel, next.js, publish, vps, deploying

I used Laravel as Backend for my project and it works properly in my VPS
these are routes reserved for my Laravel

```
/admin/ //back office
/api/  //for api
```

I ran Nextjs locally very good with port 3000 but I want to run Nextjs as frontend application with many problems

When I ran this command it returned this error:

```
npm run build
npm run start
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::80
```

Also I mapped my httpd vhost to /var/www/html/laravel-app/ which this directory placed Laravel files and /var/www/html/next-app/ placed Next.js file

Finally I want these routing work properly:

1. example.com/admin laravel
2. example.com/api Laravel
3. example.com/products Next.Js

Comment: Add both virtual host config.
Add package.json commands data.

Comment: Please tell me more, tnx

Comment: I'm assuming your frontend application has a package.json file, whether it's built into Laravel or outside. You posted that you have a port utilization error, that is because your server (apache, nginx or whatever) is using port 80. The problem is that we need to know why or at what point your application is trying to use port. 80, which is already in use. For that you need to see what is behind the commands that are embedded in your package.json file.

Comment: Can I use apache proxy and apache document root together?

Comment: Only Laravel:`<VirtualHost 194.5.175.204:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/online-shop/public
    UserDir disabled
    ServerName localhost
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/homedir.log homedir
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log

    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
        SuexecUserGroup webapps webapps
    </IfModule>
   </VirtualHost>`

Comment: Only Nextjs:`<VirtualHost 194.5.175.204:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  

    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
        SuexecUserGroup webapps webapps
    </IfModule>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia Full
    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
   
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: You cannot use 2 virtualhost with same serverName and port. You can use subdomains, for example, first virtualhost, for Laravel, `ServerName localhost` and for the other virtualhost (proxy for NestJS) `ServerName front.localhost`